# Why is this Sea Turtle yawning?

Tags: zoology, marine-biology

I found [this video online of a Green Sea Turtle lying down on a sea sponge and letting out a big yawn](https://v.redd.it/dtgq92a8w9071/DASH_720.mp4).  Here is a screenshot of the video, just incase the link doesn't work:

[image: Green Sea Turtle Yawning]

As far as I understand, Sea Turtles breathe air like we do, and effectively hold their breath underwater.  Also, as far as I understand, yawning is common to most vertebrates and it is believed to be triggered by the brain when there isn't enough oxygen in the blood.

If all of this is true, why is this Sea Turtle yawning underwater?  If it's not breathing the water like a fish would, surely the yawning wouldn't have the intended effect of putting more oxygen in its blood?  Is my understanding here correct?  And if it is, can someone please explain the benefits of a Sea Turtle yawning underwater?

Comment: The purpose of yawning is not clear, the "triggered by the brain when there isn't enough oxygen" explanation is just one and doesn't have much supporting evidence. It's also unclear to me whether this turtle is actually yawning or not, and I certainly don't think that can be assumed. Possibly someone else will be more familiar with sea turtle behavior, though.

Comment: @BryanKrause It does look like a yawn to me, but then again you are making me wonder if I am anthropomorphizing this turtle?

Comment: Bored with trivial questions on SE Biology?